# MVVMLight Event to Command usando Model para o Command Parameter

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm, binding

Eu venho tentando usar o Event to Command do MVVMLight para ligar os comandos do meu ViewModel a eventos como TextChanged do TextBox, por exemplo. Mas o Event to Command automaticamente assume que o Command Parameter é o Event Args do TextChanged. Eu não quero isso, o que eu preciso é enviar o model como Command Parameter, assim:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Valor, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CVTStringTODecimal}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="LightGray">
    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=usr_Receita, Path=DataContext.ModificacaoAgendaReceita}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

ModificacaoAgendaReceita é o nome do comando associado com o seguinte método, que possui o parâmetro `obj` como argumento:

```
public void ModificarAgendaReceita(object obj)
{
    var p_atual = (ModelAgendaReceita)obj;
    var p_inicial = ListaAgendaReceitaInicial.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == p_atual.ID);

    if (p_inicial != null) p_atual.Status = ModelAgendaReceita.ValidarAlteracao(p_inicial, p_atual);
}
```

Como o TextBox está dentro de um Listview, o `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` deveria enviar o `ModelAgendaReceita`, que é o model que alimenta o ItemsSource do ListView. O Event to Command continua passando o TextChangedEventArgs como CommandParameter, e eu preciso do Model.

Alguém sabe uma solução pra isso? Todo conselho/ajuda será bem vindo!